# dpkg error: files list file for package ... contains empty filename

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, gcc

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. I'm new to Ubuntu.

While attempting to install gcc I'm facing this problem:

`sudo apt-get install gcc`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gcc-11 libasan6 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev libgcc-11-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libnsl-dev libtirpc-dev
  libtsan0 libubsan1 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev rpcsvc-proto
Suggested packages:
  gcc-multilib make autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc gcc-11-multilib gcc-11-doc gcc-11-locales glibc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc gcc-11 libasan6 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev libgcc-11-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libnsl-dev libtirpc-dev
  libtsan0 libubsan1 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev rpcsvc-proto
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/35.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 116 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package libcc1-0:amd64.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'm17n-db' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: you have previously unselected package libcc1-0:amd64. please fix that first and you can install another package.

Comment: @Sad3ng I don't see why that would be a problem. It looks like the list file for m17n-db needs to be replaced.

Comment: @Zanna you are right the OP need to reinstall m17n-db package.

Comment: I think deleting that particular list file and running `sudo apt install --reinstall m17n-db` and then `sudo apt update` would be the answer, but I am unable to test right now. Hope someone would be able to write an answer accordingly

Comment: @Zanna It's not working, problem still remains... :'(

Comment: Is the output different? If so, update your question with the new output. Maybe the database got corrupted for some reason. What was done on the system that might have caused the problem?